# WiX with a code example

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix, installation, wix3

I am looking for a precise tutorial of WiX with a project example, if possible. Current tutorials didn't help me a lot.

My requirements are

- Including dependencies.
- Adding registry entries.
- Creating folders under the application folder.
- Adding a custom UI Dialog with browse button.
- Creating shortcuts on the desktop and start menu.

I have [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) with WiX 3.0.5419.0 installed.

Comment: Did you check out http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/ ?

Comment: I did, the scope of the article is large. I would take time to read it but for now need a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Creating directories

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ShortcutFolder" Name="My app">
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="My Company" Name="My Company">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My product">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

You can nest Directory tags as you like and after that use DirectoryRef to list components that go into this directory.

#### Adding a custom UI Dialog with a browse button

You can define [UIRef](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_uiref.htm) with *[WixUI_InstallDir](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm)* somewhere in a [Fragment](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_fragment.htm), [Include](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_include.htm), or [Module](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_module.htm) (not in [Product](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_product.htm), despite the documentation):

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

This will create a package that uses InstallDir UI, for example, the target directory can be specified in the UI (in case you mean this, otherwise you'll need to define a new dialog from scratch/copy an existing one and insert it into the sequence.)

#### Adding registry entries

Specify something like

```
<RegistryKey Action="none" Root="HKCU" Key="some key">
    <RegistryValue Value="some value" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
</RegistryKey>
```

inside a component.

#### Creating shortcuts on the desktop and start menu

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ShortcutFolder">
    <Component Id="ShortcutsComponent" Guid="{XXXX}">
        <CreateFolder Directory="ShortcutFolder" />

        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShorcutFolder" Directory="ShortcutFolder" On="uninstall" />

        <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
                  Name="Uninstall my product"
                  Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                  Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
                  Directory="ShortcutFolder"
                  Description="Uninstalls my product"/>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Note the use of ShortcutFolder directory from the directory list I showed earlier.

#### Including dependencies

Not quite sure which dependencies you mean.

.NET Framework? Example:

```
<Condition Message="This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 or later to be installed.">
    Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK35 OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL
</Condition>
```

Third-party DLLs? You just create a separate component for every DLL and specify the path where WiX should look for it using the `File` tag. This component then is listed under a `DirectoryRef` tag that specifies where the file goes during install.